What are the Exact Bounds on the Length of Linear Path Schemas and Number of Loops in 2-VASS Reachability?
I'm currently studying the complexity of the reachability problem in two-dimensional vector addition systems with states (2-VASS), as described in the paper "Reachability in Two-Dimensional Vector Addition Systems with States is PSPACE-Complete" by Blondin et al.
While it is known that reachability paths can be represented using linear path schemas

I am particularly interested in the exact bounds (not asymptotic () notation) on the following:

Length of the Linear Path Schema (∣∣):
What is the precise bound on the length of such schemas in terms of the number of states (∣∣) and transitions (∣∣)?

Number of Loops (Cycles):
What is the exact upper bound on the number of loops  in a linear path schema?



I don't believe anyone has carried out the analysis. Specifically, some O() stem from the lemma about cones. Have you tried following the various constructions? Is there any particular place that is problematic to work out?
